# SQL Query - performance in update/delete statements when we use primary key in the where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, syntax, partitioning

I have a question about update/delete statements in order to optimize queries in my app.

Does it ever make sense to add something else to a `where` clause in order to speed up the query if we already have a primary key in the clause?

Is it ever worth to add other indexes in the statements (besides the primary key)? It will have an impact on query performance? Probably a negative impact because of additional step? Am I right?

Is it ever worth to indicate a specific partition in the `where` clause (besides the primary key) if we know which partition the record is on?

Will it speed up the query or slow it down, because the query will use the B-Tree (primary key) in the first step to search for the given record and no need other steps?

Comment: Such general question is *off topic*. Please post your table DDL incl. index definition. This is *higly* relevant, e.g. if you have a *local* index, you will profit from *partition pruning*. The *first* thing you should learn how to get and read is the [execution plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122) of your query.

Comment: Is the primary key only used in equality conditions?

Answer (score -2):

the where clause is only there to delimit the SQL statement. The primary key is only responsible for non-double scoring

I tested it:

a table with primary-key: 4,5 sec
without primary-key: 3,8 sec

Comment: Adding indexes _may_ (or may not) help with the performance of a given SELECT statement, but they will _always_ create more overhead for INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE, due to the added work of maintaining the indexes with the inserted, updated, or deleted data.